# Smallest even number.

Tags: number-theory

Let $N$ be an even number. What is the smallest even number $d$ that divides $N$ such that $N/d$ is odd? I know the answer has to be a power of 2 (and not just a multiple of 2). But why?

Comment: Are you referring to natural numbers? The smallest even number that will divide N in that case is $2$.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "smallest" and not "largest"? The smallest would be 2. If " "largest" you probably don't want to count the number itself. Now work out some examples - what is the answer for 24?

Comment: Sorry!! Result will be odd number.Example,24=8*3.So answer is 3.

Comment: Please edit the question.

Comment: Hint: factor $N$ into its prime factors.

Comment: Hint: Product of (any number of) odd numbers is odd, product of 2 with any number is even, consider prime factorization of $N$. (Should be easy to see from there)

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: "Every integer, greater than one, has a unique prime factorization"

In symbols:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{N} : x = p_{1}^{\alpha_1}p_{2}^{\alpha_2}p_{3}^{\alpha_3}\ldots, \quad \text{where } p_{n} \in \mathbb{P}, \alpha_n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Since $2$ is a prime, we can say:

$$x =2^{n}\cdot p_{2}^{\alpha_2}p_{3}^{\alpha_3}\ldots$$

If $x$ is even, $n>0$ ...

Then divide by $2^{n}$

$$\frac{x}{2^{n}}=p_{2}^{\alpha_2}p_{3}^{\alpha_3}\ldots$$

Then you have to just prove that the left side is odd... (Hint: $2$ is the only even prime number)